# what is best site to study Spring and Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am wiling to learn the Spring and Hibernate in java ? So what is best site to study Spring and Hibernate ?Thanks in advance...

Comment: It is [google](http://google.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [official Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate) is very good.

Comment: Thank you.Found a good one...